# pod lib lint failed to validate a Kotlin multiplatform library

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

we are following the KMM documentation to build a very simple library available for our IOS and Android apps.

Following the sample project generated by android studio for a KMM library, we were able to  install and intergrate manually the library built, in a IOS project.

Now we are trying to publish this library on cocoapod and make it available for installation.

The lib is called shared.. a shared.podspec is generated..
if we run

`pod lib lint shared/shared.podspec  --verbose`

we have an error

`Testing with xcodebuild.
-> shared (0.3)

```
- WARN  | url: The URL (https://github.com/OUR_REPO_URL) is not reachable.
- WARN  | http: The URL (``) doesn't use the encrypted HTTPS protocol. It is crucial for Pods to be transferred over a secure protocol to protect your users from man-in-the-middle attacks. This will be an error in future releases. Please update the URL to use https.
- WARN  | [iOS] license: Unable to find a license file
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using codesigning identity override: -
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Build preparation complete
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Building targets in dependency order
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')`
```

Scrolling up to the error I got:

`
/bin/sh -c /Users/andreadg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-aamafucqqbvtfsfaselpdjormnrg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/shared.build/Script-46EB2E000002E0.sh
REPO_ROOT="$PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT"
"$REPO_ROOT/../gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT" $KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH:syncFramework                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.archs="$ARCHS"                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration="$CONFIGURATION"

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Directory '/' does not contain a Gradle build.

A Gradle build should contain a 'settings.gradle' or 'settings.gradle.kts' file in its root directory. It may also contain a 'build.gradle' or 'build.gradle.kts' file.

To create a new Gradle build in this directory run 'gradlew init'
```

`

Project structure below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwnz5.png)

Any idea?

also
pod repo push fails
we tried to publish the library manually ignoring the lint , and it installed with no errors but it fails later during the build of the ios project.

kdoctor doesn't give any error. All good.